# How are we using Arguments in the Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I was reading some code where programmer first defined

```
   typedef void* BLUEVELVETC_HANDLE;
```

and than he used this variable in a struct.

```
struct ThreadArgs
{
    BLUEVELVETC_HANDLE pSDK;
    EBlueVideoChannel nVideoOutputChannel;
    BLUE_U32 VideoModeExt;
    EUpdateMethod UpdateFormat;
    EMemoryFormat MemoryFormat;
};
```

than he created a new thread and sent the struct as argument.

```
ThreadArgs args;
args.pSDK = pSDKOut;
args.nVideoOutputChannel = BLUE_VIDEOCHANNEL_A;
args.VideoModeExt = VideoModeExt;
args.UpdateFormat = UpdateFormat;
args.MemoryFormat = MemoryFormat;

unsigned int ThreadId = 0;
g_hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &PlaybackThreadFifoMode, &args, CREATE_SUSPENDED,&ThreadId);
```

and finally in this function he used the arguments.

```
  unsigned int __stdcall PlaybackThreadFifoMode(void* pArg)

  unsigned int __stdcall PlaybackThreadFifoMode(void* pArg)
 {
     ThreadArgs* pArgs = (ThreadArgs*)pArg;
    BLUEVELVETC_HANDLE pSDK = pArgs->pSDK;
 }
```

Can somebody kindly explain me what this code means.

Comment: I'm not fully sure. Is the programmer still around? Perhaps you could ask him.

Comment: @Chipster if he was i would definitely had asked him.

Comment: Have you tried `man _beginthreadex`? Or corresponding article in MSDN? AFAIR thread procedure accepts generic void pointer as a user-defined parameter. Next you typecast assuming it's of same type used during thread spawn.
Don't see any magic here, it was just the same years ago

Comment: @shomit Got you. Well then, let's start here: what about it confuses you? Are you asking what the arguments are supposed to be?

Comment: @Chipster why is he passing parameter to the thread.

Comment: and than he retrieves them in the next function.

Comment: @shomit Passing the parameter to the thread as it's used somewhere with thread function, I believe. Cannot get what you're confused of.
Do you understand what _threads_ are correctly?

Comment: I think he's trying to pass data to the thread. If I'm not mistaken, thread functions usually only accept 1 argument. This way he can pass multiple arguments so to speak via a struct. But again, not 100% sure.

Comment: @Chipster exactly

Comment: @shomit you're welcome. I put it in an answer for you.

Comment: @shomit now that you understand, please rewrite it using `std::thread`, much more easy to read and maintain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best answer to questions like "why did a programmer do it like this?" is to ask them. That's usually the only satisfactory answer. In events like this where the original programmer is no longer around, a satisfactory answer is unfortunately highly unlikely.

That said, what I can tell you is that what is *likely* going on in this instance is that this programmer seems to be using a technique that allows him to pass multiple arguments to a thread function. Normally, thread functions only accept 1 argument. By passing a struct, the programmer can effectively pass multiple arguments.

Of course, since you are not truly passing these arguments, the programmer will have to pack everything in a struct and unpack it inside the thread. However, the effect is roughly the same: the thread now can accept multiple values instead of 1.